# all boot options are tried.

Tags: boot, bios, reboot

I can't instal windows and I put the HDD other laptop and there I install windows. But after, when I put the HDD on the Samsung NP300E5C when I stat the laptop open with this:
"all boot options are tried. press f4 key to recover with factory image using recovery or any other keys for next boot loop iteration."

I try to press all keys for enter in BIOS. I try with external keyboard, to boot with windows DVD, stick bootable..but nothing. Just restart and shutdown. Can somebody help me?

Comment: The installation is suited for the computer you installed it on, you must install it using the target device for it to work

Comment: but i can't. I can boot nothing here. I want to enter in BIOS

Comment: did you try pressing the f10 key while starting the laptop?

Comment: all keys...not just f10 - and I try with external keyboard...

Comment: How much time its taking to restart and shutdowm?

Comment: just some seconds

Comment: Insert a win10 CD, shut down your laptop and get your HDD out. Start your laptop and the recovery screen should appear. Go to Troubleshoot, Advanced Options and click on UEFI Firmware Settings. This should get you into BIOS. From here go to Advanced and disable Fast Bios Mode, then go to BOOT tab and disable Secure Boot.  `Fast BIOS Mode is technology to reduce the boot up time by skipping the USB check in the POST stage* DOS mode booting is not supported. (Basic ODD, USB memory devices, etc.)`

Comment: @User552853 just win 10? just dvd? why not 8 or 7? why not USB?

Comment: @Gabriel Win8,8.1,10 (win7 doesn't have that option). If Fast Boot is enabled it will not allow you to boot from USB.

Comment: @User552853 I allready try with 8 and 8.1, but now I try with 10

Comment: @User552853 it is not working. I insert DVD with win 10 and after I press F4 it's restart and then shutdown :(

Comment: @User552853 thank you :) you are the best... anyway..I know that before :)) but just now I tried...:)) but now it is going

Comment: @Gabriel glad I could help and you managed to solve your problem. :) I will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Acquire a Windows 8/8.1/10 CD and insert it into your CD/DVD unit
- Shut down your laptop and remove your HDD
- Start your laptop and the recovery screen should appear
- Go to Troubleshoot, Advanced Options and click on `UEFI Firmware Settings`. This should get you into BIOS.
- In BIOS go to Advanced and disable `Fast Bios Mode`, then go to the `BOOT` tab and disable Secure Boot.

**Info:**

`Fast BIOS Mode is technology to reduce the boot up time by skipping the USB check in the POST stage* DOS mode booting is not supported. (Basic ODD, USB memory devices, etc.)`